# Electron works, a bit...?

Tags: node.js, electron

I installed the latest version of node and electron and tried out the samples. They work when I enter "npm start".
However: when I try to make an app in another folder and launch it, I get this npm-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.11.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle proton-template-app@1.0.0~prestart: proton-template-app@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle proton-template-app@1.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle proton-template-app@1.0.0~start: proton-template-app@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle proton-template-app@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle proton-template-app@1.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/erik/Projects/Electron/tmp2/node_modules/.bin:/home/erik/bin:/home/erik/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
10 verbose lifecycle proton-template-app@1.0.0~start: CWD: /home/erik/Projects/Electron/tmp2
11 silly lifecycle proton-template-app@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'electron .' ]
12 info lifecycle proton-template-app@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: proton-template-app@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
13 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:33:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
14 verbose pkgid proton-template-app@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/erik/Projects/Electron/tmp2
16 error Linux 4.4.0-79-generic
17 error argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
18 error node v6.11.2
19 error npm  v3.10.10
20 error file sh
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno ENOENT
23 error syscall spawn
24 error proton-template-app@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
24 error spawn ENOENT
25 error Failed at the proton-template-app@1.0.0 start script 'electron .'.
25 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
25 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the proton-template-app package,
25 error not with npm itself.
25 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
25 error     electron .
25 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
25 error     npm bugs proton-template-app
25 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
25 error     npm owner ls proton-template-app
25 error There is likely additional logging output above.
26 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I'm afraid my install wasn't 100% ok, what should I do? Install again? How do I uninstall correctly? - I'm stuck, please help ;-)

Comment: Did you install Electron using the -g flag with npm? If not, Electron gets only installed into the directory you were currently in, the samples folder, I suppose...

Comment: To be honest: I'm not sure... How do I check? What is the right command?

Comment: The right command would be to cd into your project's directory and then do `npm install --save-dev electron`, so that it is saved as "Dev-Dependency" in your package.json

Answer (score 1):

The technicality is in your package.json, and your installation of Electron, but this is regardless of having it saved under `dependencies`.

If your `start` script in package.json calls `electron .`, you will need to install Electron globally with `npm install electron -g`. This goes for all commands where you use the name, much like `mocha` and `cordova create`. Just some examples.

To use it locally (non-globally) and only inside the project, you can just call `npm install electron` (which you may have done), but your `start`script will have to point to the `electron` file inside the local `node_modules` folder. Usually the path is `node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd`, and your start script can look like `node_modules/.bin/electron .`

**If you ever come across this problem inside an IDE, you should set `electron.cmd` in `.bin` as your executable, then `.` as your arguments.**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed `electron` globally, to do so run the following command:

`npm install -g electron`

Once you have installed it try running `electron` in your command prompt it should open a demo app.

---

To uninstall electron from the global scope:
`npm uninstall -g electron`